# Unable to install or update packages due to bluez not configured

Tags: apt, gnome

I recently tried to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS i.e "do-release-upgrade", I am not sure what went wrong but whenever I try to install or update a package I get the below error,

```
~/COREBOOT/coreboot.org_3rdAug$ sudo apt-get install libftdi1 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libftdi1 is already the newest version (0.20-4build1).
libftdi1 set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up bluez (5.37-0ubuntu5) ...
insserv: Service dbus has to be enabled to start service bluetooth
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5.5); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-bluetooth:
 indicator-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
 indicator-bluetooth depends on gnome-bluetooth | ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-control-center:
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-bluetooth; however:
  Package indicator-bluetooth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problemsNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                              No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                               No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                 - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-user-share:
 gnome-user-share depends on gnome-bluetooth (>= 3.9.3); however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-user-share (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-core:
 gnome-core depends on gnome-bluetooth (>= 3.14); however:
  Package gnome-bluetooth is not configured yet.
 gnome-core depends on gnome-user-share (>= 3.14); however:
  Package gnome-user-share is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on unity-control-center; however:
  Package unity-control-center is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5.23); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
 gnome-bluetooth
 indicator-bluetooth
 unity-control-center
 gnome-user-share
 gnome-core
 ubuntu-desktop
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I figure that this could be be because of

```
    Setting up bluez (5.37-0ubuntu5) ...
insserv: Service dbus has to be enabled to start service bluetooth
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:
 gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5.5); however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
```

and I tried restarting the dbus service

However I end up with the below error

```
$ sudo service dbus restart
Failed to restart dbus.service: Operation refused, unit dbus.service may be requested by dependency only.
See system logs and 'systemctl status dbus.service' for details.
```

Output of `systemctl status dbus.service`

```
dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-08-04 18:54:45 IST; 4 days ago 
    Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
 Process: 2774 ExecReload=/usr/bin/dbus-send --print-reply --system --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.ReloadConfig (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 3054 (dbus-daemon)
  CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service 
          └─3054 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

but:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure bluez Setting up bluez (5.37-0ubuntu5) ... 
insserv: Service dbus has to be enabled to start service   
bluetooth insserv: exiting now! update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1    
Errors were encountered while processing: bluez
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: @Zanna, looks like the service is running
`Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-08-04 18:54:45 IST; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:dbus-daemon(1)
  Process: 2774 ExecReload=/usr/bin/dbus-send --print-reply --system --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.ReloadConfig (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3054 (dbus-daemon)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           └─3054 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation`

Comment: @Zanna,  
`$ sudo dpkg --configure bluez

Setting up bluez (5.37-0ubuntu5) ...
insserv: Service dbus has to be enabled to start service bluetooth
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez`

Comment: I got this error today on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on bluez upgrade to 5.37-0ubuntu5.1. I reported [bug 1719283](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1719283). These actions solved my problem: `sudo update-rc.d dbus defaults`, `sudo update-rc.d bluetooth defaults`, `sudo apt-get install -f`.